# Why Room ORM creates too many dao instances

Tags: android, android-room, dao

I am using Room ORM to cache some data in my application.
when I execute multiple queries, too many DAO instances are created.

this is the code Room uses to provide DAO

```
public DatabaseDao getDatabaseDao() {
    if (_databaseDao != null) {
      return _databaseDao;
    } else {
      synchronized(this) {
        if(_databaseDao == null) {
          _databaseDao = new DatabaseDao_Impl(this);
        }
        return _databaseDao;
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see only one instance of DAO is created

but when I profile the app, I see multiple *DatabaseDao_Impl* is created.

[image]

Is this a problem of Room?

Comment: did you checked RoomDatabase class? it should be singleton too

Comment: Yes. It is singleton.